# How to use the one fragment in three different activities

Tags: android, navigation, fragment

I need to do a Fragment that works for all activities (like a banner or something).

I have a HomeActivity, IncidentActivity, ScheludeActivity, etc. but I need to do a fragment or something that could be accessed from all those activities but it need to be instantiate once because it will have a, webview that I don't want to be reloading everytime I change of activity.

Can you give me some advise?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a BaseActivity which these three activities extend from this. The instance of fragment should be single. Your fragment should be retainable(setRetainInstance(true)). Do not forget, you should use the same instance of your Fragment! So, you can control fragment instance in your BaseActivity.